# How can I change the MUI Badge component and add text inside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to add a label next to my new row after adding it to the table. I found MUI Badge. How could I change the number and replace it with the word New?
Something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcwlr.png)
This is the component:

```
export default function SimpleBadge() {
  return (
    <Badge badgeContent={4} color="primary">
      <MailIcon color="action" />
    </Badge>
  );
}
```

Do you know if that's possible? or do you know any alternative?

Comment: There's a component called `Chip` on material ui, I think you should try to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code:

```
<Badge badgeContent={'success'} color="primary" />
```